# Detect "Show virtual keyboard" setting programatically in Android

Tags: android

There's a setting in Android called "Show virtual keyboard", which in my phone is located in:
`Settings > Languages & input > Physical keyboard`. It controls whether to keep the virtual keyboard on the screen while a physical keyboard is active.

Is there a way of programatically querying whether it is enabled or disabled? I can't find it in the [Settings.System list in Android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if you can query that information but if it helps you, there is a way to programatically detect if the keyboard is opened or not.

```
private boolean isKeyboardShowing = false;

private void detectKeyboard() {
    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    int screenHeight = rootView.getRootView().getHeight();

                    int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

                    if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                        // keyboard is opened
                        if (!isKeyboardShowing) {
                            isKeyboardShowing = true;

                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // keyboard is closed
                        if (isKeyboardShowing) {
                            isKeyboardShowing = false;
               
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```